# Convergence in integral norm

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $f_n$ be a bounded sequence in $L^1$ norm that converges pointwise to $f\in L^1$.
I have to show that 
$$||f_n||_1-||f_n-f||_1\to ||f||_1$$
I tried to use the Lebesgue theorem but I cannot guarantee that there is a function in $L^1$ that bounds all $f_n$ pointwise. I cannot use Peppo Levi theorem since there is no monothone convergence and I tried with Fatou's lemma without getting anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reversed triangle inequality give us
$$
||f_n(x)|-|f_n(x)-f(x)||\leqslant |f_n(x)-f_n(x)+f(x)|=|f(x)|
$$
Now apply the dominated convergence theorem.